# ValueError: unsupported format character 'p' (0x70) at index 7

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I am trying to format the string file name by using a loop here is my code

```
for i in range(1, 16):
    bgImageFile = ("bg_%01.png" %i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax requires `%d` (or `%s`), not just `%`:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    bgImageFile = 'bg_%s01.png'%i
    print(bgImageFile)

bg_101.png
bg_201.png
bg_301.png
```

With Python 3.6+, you can use f-strings ([PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    bgImageFile = f'bg_{i}01.png'
```

Some specifiers you should know ([source](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting)):

> `%s` - String (or any object with a string representation, like
>   numbers)
>
> `%d` - Integers
>
> `%f` - Floating point numbers
>
> `%.<number of digits>f` - Floating point with fixed amount of digits to
>   the right of the dot.
>
> `%x/%X` - Integers in hex representation
>   (lowercase/uppercase)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having another error on OpenCV imshow it says 

        cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: @Redemption, OK, if it's not connected to this question, please [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).